# Cannot generate models in Rails: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I tried to generate a model via this command:

> rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text article:references

And got the following error:

```
/Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/Github/react-on-rails-tutorial/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/Github/react-on-rails-tutorial/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/Github/react-on-rails-tutorial/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/Github/react-on-rails-tutorial/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/chowjiaying/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Here's what I've tried:

- using gem pristine --all
- uninstalling and reinstalling bootsnap
- updating bundle
- uninstalling and reinstalling bundler

I'm using Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 6.0.2.1. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to run the command with `bundle exec` before ? `bundle exec rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text article:references`

Comment: @SimonMo Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I tried it out but it didn't work.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue. I tried the following, am not sure which was the one that helped me succeed:
1. Switch to bootsnap version 1.4.2rc3 by editing Gemfile then ran bundle install.
2. I ran 'spring stop', then ran bundle exec rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text article:references
3. In Gemfile, change 'require: false' to 'require: true'.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I just spend several hours running down the same rabbit hole, after upgrading an app from ruby 2.4 to 2.6. I'm using rbenv and bundler on MacOS Mojave.

I can't pinpoint how I fixed it, but after trying lots of updates/rehash/install approaches with little success, I uninstalled about a dozen old versions of ruby and started clean. This got me past the exact error in the question.

This may be overkill, but it worked for me:

List all installed ruby versions:

```
rbenv versions
```

Uninstall all versions of Ruby.

```
rbenv uninstall 2.1
rbenv uninstall 2.1.9
etc.
```

Install needed version(s) of Ruby

```
rbenv install 2.5.6

bundle install

gem pristine --all
```

Note - `gem pristine --all` took like a half hour.